# Getting number of hits without pagination in sunspot 1.2 on ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

I've successfully installed Sunspot for my Ruby On Rails 3 project, but I can't seem to find a way to get the total hits for a search query.

this is my search request

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Job) do
    fulltext params[:job]
    paginate(:page => params[:offset], :per_page => 25)
end
```

It works well except I need to get total number of real hits, not the total results returned (in this case 25 because of :per_page => 25)

In other words, I want to be able to display: Showing 1 to 25 out of 883 jobs found

Any help would be appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method `total` works here.

```
query_results = Sunspot.search(Recipe) do
  keywords(params[:qs])
  paginate(:page=>params[:page], :per_page=>30)
end

@search_results = query_result.results
@search_total = @search_results.total
```

Or, in your view, total_entries works on the results object.

```
    %div
      Your search for 
      = params[:qs]
      returned
      = pluralize(@search_results.total_entries, 'result')
```

Comment: `total_entries` seemed to have worked in the controller for me, but not `total`.

Answer (score 3):

Never used Sunspot, but have you tried this in your view:

```
Showing #{@search.hits.page} to #{@search.hits.per_page} out of #{@search.total} jobs found
```